# Blog post revisions with moderation step database design

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to design a database for the blog posts, that can be modified and diffs in revisions can be shown. In general, the flow looks like this:

1. Create a template post. (update it at any time when in the draft state).
2. When you are done with the template, you can pass it to moderation.
3. Moderator can approve or deny your post (with the reason provided).
4. If moderation is passed, then the post is published and can be viewed by the user.
5. If the post was rejected you can apply a new version of it for moderation.
6. When the post already published you can modify it through new revision (with moderation phase also).

My current DB schema for the article looks like this:

[image: Article db schema]

And it's not satisfying my requirements. I don't know how to model the moderation process in a database, with the possible rejection reason. So with all that in mind, what is the best approach?

Comment: From a database perspective the STATUS column is necessary and sufficient. However, you claim that does not satisfy your requirements. Then you need to define those requirements. That said it seems likely to be a process not a state-of-the-database. This may NOT be the appropriate forum for your question.

Comment: Add another table, `article_review`, to keep track of the moderation action history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your question in the comments, I would structure the review history like so:

```
create table article_review_status (
  article_review_status_id int generated always as identity,
  status_code text not null unique
);

create table article_review (
  article_review_id int generated always as identity,
  article_revision_id int not null 
    references article_revision(article_revision_id),
  article_review_status_id int not null
    references article_review_status(article_review_status_id),
  entry_at timestamptz not null default now(),
  article_review_comments text,
  reviewer_id int not null
    references users(user_id) -- <-- Would this be another author or an admin?
);
```

Then your application can determine whether to make the `article` visible.